# How do I expand this sigma/summation notation?

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I don't know if it's correct to refer to this as summation notation since the operation is not addition so please correct me if that's inaccurate.

How do I expand this notation?

[image]

I believe it's [image] for `n=4`, but don't wasn't sure how to automatically expand it. Is the idea that here that we are logically *and*'ing as i varies and *or*'ing as j varies?

Another similar example I'd like some elucidation on how to properly expand is [image]

I appreciate any help clarifying how to expand such notation.

Comment: Having monoid with some operation on it, composite operation, i.e. operation on finite family of elements, we define inductively.

Comment: You're correct.